# How to create temporary file and put content inside?

Tags: node.js

How to create temporary file and put content inside and send to remote machine and delete after that.I have function which send file with scp to remote but how to create temp file and put content inside ?I looked at temp module for node.js but how to put content inside ?

Comment: Please give some of the code you are working on, along with what other steps you have tried yourself.

Answer (score 8):

There is a complete example on the node-temp website:

https://github.com/bruce/node-temp

```
var temp = require('temp');

// Automatically track and cleanup files at exit
temp.track();

var stream = temp.createWriteStream();
stream.write("Some data");

// Maybe do some other things
stream.end();
```